# Scroll Snap To Sections Without Resizing The Window

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

When the user scrolls through a page, I would like the page to snap to the next section and then center the view there. The sections are not full height, but are around 500px each, though not all the same height.

I see plenty of jQuery plugins that do this but they all resize the window. I have my div heights where I want them and can't have them be adjusted. These plugins are perfect except for the fact that the resize the section that is being scrolled to and then landed upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create your own using `.animate()` and calculating destination/direction using events fired. Refer to http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwKJaO for an example.

**Note**: The codepen is not complete and is just a rough demonstration of the functionality.